# Looping with a closure: Not working? (using jqueryui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, closures

I believe I've come up with a looping closure problem in my code. I've read [this article](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-3/)
which has been a great help. Recently I've came up with a problem similar to the section "Looping With A Closure", referenced in the article. I've tried their solution but it still didn't solve my problem. I've been searching everywhere for a solution but I always find the one in the article.

I'm using jqueryui to make some lis draggable and when I drop them in a container I need to use a variable (node) specific to that li. The problem is that the node (and the index) is always the last one (thus the closure problem).

Here is my code (I've simplified it a little bit so that it is simpler to identify the problem):

```
function makeDraggable(node, i) {
        $("#rightTab li#" + node.id).draggable({
            containment: 'div#container',
            stack: 'div#container',
            scroll: false,
            revert: 'invalid',
            helper: function() {
                return $(this).children().clone();
            },
            start: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).children().css('opacity', 0);
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).children().css('opacity', 1);
            }
        });

        $("#vis").droppable({
            drop: test(node, i)
        });
    }

    function test(noder, index) {
        return function(event, ui) {
            alert(index);
            //stuff with node.
        }
    }

    function appendInfo(nodes) {
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            $("#rightTab #content ul").append("<li id=" + nodes[i].id + "><div></div></li>");

            if(visualization.hasImageLabel) {
                interfaceHandler.handleImageLabel(nodes[i]);
            }
            if(visualization.hasTextLabel) {
                interfaceHandler.handleTextLabel(nodes[i]);
            }

            makeDraggable(nodes[i], i);
        }
    }
```

When I alert the index (in the function test) it always prints 9 (maximum array length), the node is also always the last one.

(Sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `$("#vis").droppable({...})` on every iteration through the loop. This sets up 10 `drop` event handlers; only the last one is ever fired, which was passed (node_nine, 9) as its parameters.

Check the value of `ui.draggable` inside your callback; it will tell you what the dropped element is.

Comment: Oh well. I feel so stupid right now. For some reason I thought I had to add a droppable for every draggable, but that doesn't even make sense. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$("#vis").droppable(...)` replaces any previously defined droppable functionality, so not soluble with a closure.

If it's important to know the index, then try making each draggable node aware of its own index with `.data(...)`, and call `$("#vis").droppable(...)` just once in `appendInfo()`, not in `makeDraggable()`.

```
function appendInfo(nodes) {
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        $("#rightTab #content ul").append("<li id=" + nodes[i].id + "><div></div></li>");
        if(visualization.hasImageLabel) {
            interfaceHandler.handleImageLabel(nodes[i]);
        }
        if(visualization.hasTextLabel) {
            interfaceHandler.handleTextLabel(nodes[i]);
        }
        makeDraggable(nodes[i], i);
        $(node).data('index', i); //<<< node is now aware of its own index
    }
    $("#vis").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.draggable.data('index'));//I think???
            //stuff with node.
        }
    });
}
```

If it's not necessary to know the index, then you can just access the draggable as `ui.draggable`, without setting or getting `.data()`.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks a lot. Jacob Krall had already told be that. For some reason I thought the droppable had to be added for every draggable. Oh well, no more working late for me.